# Setting up Visual Studio 2010 for learning purposes - Compiler independent and other things

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to know how to set up "Visual Studio 2010 - Ultimate" for learning purposes. I don't want it adding libraries that I forgot to add. I also don't want it correcting small mistakes that I make (Can't think of anything right now). I really enjoy using it as an IDE (Have tried a few already), but having mistakes passing by unnoticed really worries me. I don't want to go back to command-line compiling and Notepad++ though... Even if not everything can be turned off, the more automatic corrections I remove the better it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can turn off most of those features by going to Tools-Options-Text Editor, and then select your language. Then just un-check what you don't want.

[image]